# How to fix 'Argument Error in StaticPages home' issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have my app in RoR 5.2 and I receive error:

```
ArgumentError in StaticPages#home
wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
```

on first line of this code error is appearing:

```
<% if @feed_items.any? %>
  <ol class="microposts">
    <%= render @feed_items %>
  </ol>
  <%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
<% end %>
```

This error appears when I go to 'home' page, and code is here:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
  <h3>Micropost Feed</h3>
  <%= render 'shared/feed' %>
</div>
```

Also I've searched in my project directory where this instance variable '@feed_items' is involved, and it's here:

1. static_pages controller:

```
      def home
        if logged_in?
          @micropost  = current_user.microposts.build
          @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
        end
      end
```

2. microposts_contoller

```
     def create
        @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
        if @micropost.save
          flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
          redirect_to root_url
        else
          @feed_items = []
          render 'static_pages/home'
        end
      end
```

Full error here:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)):
    1: <% if @feed_items.any? %>
    2:   <ol class="microposts">
    3:     <%= render @feed_items %>
    4:   </ol>

app/views/shared/_feed.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_shared__feed_html_erb___1043087479159467025_70076005316480'
app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_static_pages_home_html_erb___2235203620896870682_70076015548660'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hm, `Enumerable#any?` should work without a block or argument.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Strange indeed. What does `@feed_items.method(:any?).source_location` return?

Comment: The behaviour is weird, as I don't see a reason for the error. It could possibly be something like "you forgot to press save on a file", or "it's not actually loading the thing that you think it is".

Comment: Try putting `<% binding.pry %>` at the top of the view. What is `@feed_items`? What is `@feed_items.method(:any?).source_location`?

Comment: He doesn't necessarily have `pry` installed. But the default `byebug` console emerging in case of error should be helpful as well.

Comment: My point is "learn how to debug the code". Use whatever debugging tool you like. `pry` is one suggestion.